# Attempted to open an MatDatepicker with no associated input

Tags: angular, angular7, mat-datepicker

I have defined this MatDatePicker:

```
 <input #creatoDal matInput [matDatepicker]="creatoDal"
                            (focus)="creatoDal.open()" readonly>
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="creatoDal"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #creatoDal></mat-datepicker>
```

It seems to me that I've bound the reference correctly, but when clicking on the datepicker it doesn't open and it gives me the following error:

> Error: Attempted to open an MatDatepicker with no associated input.
>       at MatDatepicker.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/datepicker.es5.js.MatDatepicker.open

Comment: Why did you defined two identical template reference `#creatoDal`?

Answer (score 5):

you have added hash `#creatoDal` to two elements removing it from you `input` should work for you so you code should be

```
<input  matInput [matDatepicker]="creatoDal"
                            (focus)="creatoDal.open()" readonly>
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="creatoDal"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #creatoDal></mat-datepicker>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmljws)